# Java why does no third syntax for for (each) loops exist?

Tags: java, foreach

I know that currently there are two approaches to loop over an `List`. But let's complicate it a bit more, consider:

- You iterate over `List<E> list`.
- You want to keep track of an `int y` on every iteration.
- There exists a function `process(E elem, int y)` that processes an item.

**Option 1:**

```
for (int i = 0, y = 0; i < list.size(); i++, y++) {
    process(list.get(i), y);
}
```

which actually just is

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    process(list.get(i), i);
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
int y = 0;
for (E elem : list) {
    process(elem, y);
    y++;
}
```

which can be rewritten to

```
int y = 0;
for (E elem : list) {
    process(elem, y++);
}
```

However why does the following not exist? What are the objections to it not existing?

**Option 3:**

```
for (int y = 0; E elem : list; y++) {
    process(elem, y);
}
```

Two arguments to have this construct:

- Both `foreach` syntaxes are distinguishable
- Many objects implement `Iterable<E>`, but have no `for` counterpart. This happens when an `Iterable<E>` has no order associated with it for example.

Comment: As you already provided workarounds, why would this additional syntax help at all? Compared to a regular for-loop, the foreach construct is handy in many cases. Your approach would only help in border cases.

Comment: I disagree with the downvote so +1 to balance it up. Although the question gets down to why Java does anything the way it does in the first place (spoiler: because the designers chose so), it's still a valid question. Probably a better fit for [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) though.

Comment: @Kayaman Because in the third option `y`'s scope would be limited to the `for`-loop, whereas in the second option the scope of `y` is bound to the first found surrounding scope.

Comment: @skiwi But your Option 1.2 solves that in a perfectly acceptable way. Of course if you don't have a List, but an Iterable, you'll need an extra variable there, but that's just the way it is. More syntaxes bring more confusion, so there's no reason to add everything people come up with. And there are far more useful syntaxes that would be far more beneficial than this to have in Java.

Comment: Personally I think your option 2 is clearer than your proposed option 3.  And 2 is definitely better than 1 (1 would be O(N^2) for a sequential-access list such as `LinkedList`, 2 will be O(N) for both random- and sequential-access lists).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is close to the proposed variant 3:

```
int y = 0;
for (Iterator<E> it=list.iterator(); it.hasNext(); y++) {
   process(it.next(), y);
}
```

or

```
Iterator<E> it=list.iterator();
for (int y = 0; it.hasNext(); y++) {
   process(it.next(), y);
}
```

or

```
Iterator it;int y;
for (y = 0, it=list.iterator(); it.hasNext(); y++) {
    process(it.next(), y);
}
```

Comment: You can have two declarations in one statement within for-loops. And it seems to be actually the only 'correct' solution regarding scoping.

Comment: No, two declarations are prohibited, only two (or more) `StatementExpression`s, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1.1 I added third variant to my answer.

Comment: You can declare two (or more) variables in one declaration but only if they're the same type, i.e. `for(int i = 0, j = 5; i < 5; i++, j--)` is OK, but `for(int i = 0, String s = ""; .....` is not.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's excessive? In this case `y` doesn't bear any sense and code can be easily rewritten as you've shown.

If you want such a nonstandard behaviour, maybe try to look at Scala language, for example. You'll be able to create truly monstrous control structures there.

Comment: Or Groovy - [eachWithIndex](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#eachWithIndex(groovy.lang.Closure)) does exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This :

```
for (int y = 0; E elem : list; y++) {
   process(elem, y);
}
```

can very well be written as this :

```
E elem;
for (int y = 0 ; y < list.size(); y++, elem = list.get(y)) {
    process(elem, y);
}
```

Though the scope of the variable `elem` differs in this case . Hence I don't think there is an explicit need for the 3rd option , again , opinions may vary .

Comment: This is the case because `List<E>` has `.size()` and `.get(int i)`. And I agree that the third option would not be interesting for those cases, it however is interesting for `Iterable<E>` that do not have access to the `.size()` and `.get(int i)`, and there are plenty out there.

Answer (score 0):

In a language like Python, this could be solved by zipping with an integer sequence:

```
>>> a = ['a','b','c','d']
>>> for val,i in zip(a, range(len(a))):
...   print val, i
...
a 0
b 1
c 2
d 3
```

Obviously Java doesn't have syntactic support for something like this, but I do think there can be good reasons for avoiding calling `list.get(i)` on each iteration, not least that fetching a specific value might be much slower than iterating to the next value (say, with a linked list).

I'm not a fan of departing from convention when using loop syntax, so I'm not so keen on putting different variables in the test and increment portions of a normal for-loop (Alexei Kaigorodov's solution looks nice, but potentially confusing for people who aren't familiar with it).  My usuallly-preferred solution is to maintain the count separately while using a for-each loop, which is the OP's Option 2.

Alternatively, you could use my [CountingIterable<>](https://github.com/andrewaylett/iterables) class, which provides the count as well as the value.  Whether this is a good idea in production code is still up for debate, but the question inspired me to write it and [stick it on Github](https://github.com/andrewaylett/iterables).

It's used like this:

```
for (Counted<E> v : counting(iterable)) {
    process(v.getValue(), v.getCount());
}
```

(Where, in the code this was taken from, `counting` is statically imported from the `Counting` class)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is an opinion based question. Only the language designers could answer that.

You could somewhat improve the `Iterator` syntax with a utility class, if you are willing to accept the creation of a new object that wraps `Iterator` to make the index available. See an example below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList( new String[] {"item1", "item2", "item3"} );

    for (IndexIterator<String> it = IndexIterator.of(list.iterator()); it.hasNext();) {
        System.out.println( it.next() + " : " + it.index() );
    }
    // Prints:
    // item1 : 0
    // item2 : 1
    // item3 : 2
}
```

The `IndexIterator` utility class is as follows:

```
public static class IndexIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
    private int index = -1;
    private Iterator<T> iterator;
    public IndexIterator(Iterator<T> it) {
        this.iterator = it;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return iterator.hasNext();
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        index++;
        return iterator.next();
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        iterator.remove();
    }

    public int index() {
        return this.index;
    }

    public static <T> IndexIterator<T> of(Iterator<T> it) {
        return new IndexIterator<T>(it);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Isn't

```
nextIndex()
```

what you are looking for instead of y? 
P.s. using ListIterator

Edited:
this is what I meant in code:

```
Iterator<E> it = list.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()){
    process(it.next(), it.previousIndex());
}
```

Comment: It might be a solution for some specific cases, but it should solve all cases.

Comment: @skiwi There hasn't been a syntax invented yet that would solve all cases.

Comment: @skiwi, I added a sample code of what i meant. Wouldn't this solution be general and simpler?

Comment: @azzurroverde Ah, so you meant `Iterator<List>`? I thought you were talking about some userdefined class `ListIterator`.

Comment: Well, someone voted it down. Why? What's wrong with it? Care to explain?